# Gulp install works but gulp is not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I am following the "gulp quick start" and everything is getting installed without error messages neither warnings. But when I try to check the gulp version on the end of the "gulp quick start" it returns 
`'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

The gulp quick start: [GULP](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start)

When I check the first things in the "gulp quick start" the "check for node,npm and npx" it all works fine. I am getting normal responses.

The next step is installing gulp

When I install gulp evereything goes whell, the files are being created there our no error/ warnings displayed.

BUT when I am trying to run a gulp command on the end of the installation to test if gulp works. it returns `gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

I tried installing it multiple times. I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Any help is welcome.

My device is running windows 10

Comment: Try `npx gulp whatever`, gulp is likely not installed globally.  Either that or do `npm -g i gulp`.

Comment: @zero298 I did install gulp globally when I try your first suggestion i am getting the return `[22:22:55] Local gulp not found in ~\Documents\example\example\example 
[22:22:55] Try running: npm install gulp` when I try your second suggestion I am getting the message that gulp is already installed

Comment: Did you restart your command line, under certain conditions, you need to restart it to see new commands.

Comment: @Ferrybig i did. I even restarted my pc a few times.

Comment: That's might be helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows/9588052#9588052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but... my npm was broken.

I tried to download something with npm but that did not work ass well so I figured my npm was broken.

When I reinstalled npm everything worked fine.