# 'npm ls' shows module, but require() cannot find it

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the module `type` installed:

```
$ npm ls type
serverless-commerce@5.0.0 C:\Users\user\Documents\appname
`-- type@0.0.3
```

However `require` cannot find it:

```
$ node
> require('type')
{ Error: Cannot find module 'type'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15) 
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you look into type's package.json and check name and main properties?

Comment: @bigless Yep I tried that, indeed that was the cause. I've just seen your suggestion now but still upvoting it as it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the issue was created by [a badly formed package](https://github.com/Gozala/type) with:

- no `index.js`
- a missing [`main` entry in `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) to specify an alternative.

Adding the line `"main": "checks.js",` to `package.json` makes the module work

```
node
> require('type')
{ isBoolean: [Function: isBoolean],     
isUndefined: [Function: isUndefined], 
isNull: [Function: isNull],
isString: [Function: isString],
isNumber: [Function: isNumber],
isObject: [Function: isObject],
instanceOf: [Function: instanceOf],
isRegExp: [Function: isRegExp],
isDate: [Function: isDate],
isFunction: [Function: isFunction],
isArray: [Function: isArray],
isArguments: [Function: isArguments],
isPrimitive: [Function: isPrimitive],
isFlat: [Function: isFlat],
isEmpty: [Function: isEmpty],
isJSON: [Function] }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring the package to look in `module.paths`. which may not have the right path `C:\Users\user\Documents\appname`.

You an either:

- set a relative path `require('.type')`
- set a fully qualified path `require('C:\Users\user\Documents\appname\type')`

Comment: My understanding in that require looks in `node_modules` recursively - and that if `npm ls` shows it, it should be findable by `require`. Otherwise I'd have to use a relative or FQ path names for every module - which I (and every does node user) does not.

Comment: it also may just be a windows thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows