# Why do npm packages resolve from /AppData and not from local /node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

When developing locally in VS Code, packages are resolving to `C:/Users/<User>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/3.5/node_modules/@types/<package>/index` and not from the `/node_modules` directory local to the package.json.

I'm not getting any compiling errors or when deploying, but I can't wrap my head around why it's not resolving to the location I'd expect it to. Any idea why and how to fix it?

I'm using Node 8.12 and NPM 6.4.1.

Here's an example
[image: screenshot example]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "superapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You installed the package globally at some point. See the answer in for details on global package installation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827950/packages-installed-from-admin-cmd-powershell-not-added-to-path-for-regular-cmd-p/56828188?noredirect=1#comment100209865_56828188

Answer (score 0):

Your module in question `@types/express` is not present in package.json

```
npm install @types/express --save-dev
```

You may have installed it globally previously and that is why it can be found in `AppData` as a backup solution for the compiler