# 'graphql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. While deploying prisma

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, command-line-interface, prisma

I have a problem with `prisma deploy` command `post-deploy:
'graphql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
I have tried any way to solve this trouble. I've changed, deleted, etc `PATH` var.[proof that I've changed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE1yW.png)
Also I've checked if I correctly installed `qraphql` and `prisma` globally and locally. Interesting that this error only with `graphql`(this error shows when I simply write `graphql` command).
I am almost sure that its windows problem because I've tried reinstall `NPM` and `NodeJS` at all.
[that error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PD1u.png)

> Deploying service `shishy-bed` to stage `dev` to server `prisma-eu1` 656ms
>   Service is already up to date.
>
> post-deploy:
>   'graphql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> Running graphql get-schema -p prisma...
>   Running graphql get-schema -p prisma ×

[What i've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ra9P.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: It really doesn't work for me, you can see `What i've tried` in my article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem! I don't know why, but `npm install graphql` didn't create some run files: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jlJX.png). But in many cases you should only change `PATH` variable by following this article: [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue a bunch of times and I also tried to create my PATH variable as the first answer suggested but it didn't seem to work for me. However, I installed a package named `graphql-cli` which then automatically resolved this issue.

I think maybe this is the package that needs to be present for to run graphql from the cli along with graphql.