# Where does npm install packages on Windows? Node version 10.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Can someone tell where can I find local npm modules installed using npm?
I am referring to NodeJS version 10

I do not see "npm" folder under C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming

Comment: Have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

When you install npm all of the NodeJS related dependencies are stored inside this directory

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules".