# Can't install gulp globally

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, windows-7-x64, gulp-4

I can't install gulp globally on my windows 7 machine. I used `npm install --global gulp-cli` but showed this error:

[image: this]

when i used `gulp -v` I got this error

[image]

please help

Comment: Seems fine to me, can you show what error you are getting?

Comment: Please have a look on the problem again, I have attached the screenshot of the error I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

At least, It solved! I followed this article [install gulp](https://zestcode.co.uk/how-to-install-gulp-on-windows-10/) till step #2 then I installed gulp globally on terminal using this code `npm install gulp-cli -g`.

Thank you everyone for help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this commands:
If you've previously installed gulp globally, try to delete it using:

```sh
npm rm --global gulp
```

After that install new version of gulp using:

```sh
npm install --global gulp
npm link gulp
```

and verify yourgulp version:

```sh
gulp --version
```

Comment: it did not fix it, gulp version is not showing up.

Comment: if you try gulp and click enter , can you show me what happen ?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question,  have a look.

Comment: try this command : npm install --global gulp-cli after that  gulp -v

Comment: I find that your issue resolved here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/1041104 you need , because gulp module not added to the path you can follow the response on the link to add it to the path after that try with gulp -v

Comment: It didn't fix the problem either.