# Express module install

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to install express module install, but the issue is that after installation I am still unable to use express.

What I've done:

Install express using cmd - npm install -g express

For some reason it's not installing globally.

Help?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: @BrandonPalmer Windows

Comment: [Don't install modules globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#i-installed-something-globally-but-i-can-t-require-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the following:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Source: [Issues with installing Express.JS in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663590/issues-with-installing-express-js-in-windows-7)

```
In later versions of express comand line was migrated to a separate module: express-generetor

use

npm install -g express-generator@3

and could use the express command
```