# How to npm install global not as root?

Tags: node.js, shell

I'm on a unix box where I don't have root access.

I changed my .npmrc file (in my user's root directory) to:

```
prefix=~/global_npm
```

Now when I do "npm install -g packagename" it installs inside my global_npm directory. Which is good.
And then I gave myself path access to it by updating my .bashrc file with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/global_npm/bin
```

Do I need to do anything else? I think I need to set NODE_PATH but I'm not sure?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Sindre Sorhus has a great guide at [github.com/sindresorhus/guides](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) which I've reposted here.

---

## Install npm packages globally without sudo on OS X and Linux

npm installs packages locally within your projects by default. You can also install packages globally (e.g. `npm install -g <package>`) (useful for command-line apps). However the downside of this is that you need to be root (or use `sudo`) to be able to install globally.

Here is a way to install packages globally for a given user.

#### 1. Create a directory for your global packages

```
mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

#### 2. Reference this directory for future usage in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

```
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

#### 3. Indicate to `npm` where to store your globally installed package. In your `$HOME/.npmrc` file add:

```
prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages
```

#### 4. Ensure `node` will find them. Add the following to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

```
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
```

#### 5. Ensure you'll find installed binaries and man pages. Add the following to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

```
PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
# Unset manpath so we can inherit from /etc/manpath via the `manpath`
# command
unset MANPATH # delete if you already modified MANPATH elsewhere in your config
MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
```

---

Check out [npm-g_nosudo](https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo) for doing the above steps automagically

---

**NOTE:** If you are running OS X, the `.bashrc` file may not yet exist, and the terminal will be obtaining its environment parameters from another file, such as `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. These files also reside in the user's home folder. In this case, simply adding the following line to them will instruct Terminal to also load the `.bashrc` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Put the link to the official page might be grateful as well: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Sindre's guide no longer mentions `NODE_PATH` and the entire thing is overkill vs. simply running [`npm config set prefix ~/.local ` and `PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH`](http://michaelb.org/the-right-way-to-do-global-npm-install-without-sudo/).

Answer (score 161):

Many setups already expect binaries to be found in `~/.local/bin/`. So this answer follows that convention. Other files will get installed to `~/.local/lib/node_modules/`.

### 1. Configure `npm`

Run:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.local/'
```

This modifies `~/.npmrc` to include this line:

```
prefix=~/.local/
```

### 2. Make sure `~/.local/bin` exists and is in your PATH

Run `echo "$PATH"` to have a look at your path. If it does not include `~/.local/bin/` already, you will need to configure your system to include it.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Replace `.bashrc` with the configuration file of the shell that you are using.

### 3. Install packages globally

```
npm install -g packagename
```

Comment: Also here recommended: https://michaelb.org/the-right-way-to-do-global-npm-install-without-sudo/

Comment: This should be selected as the answer. On Linux systems `~/.local` is used for such purposes by [convention](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Comment: It should be the selected answer, it is simple and beautiful. On Ubuntu it works out of box.

Comment: I have used this several times now. It simply works, easily and flawlessly.

Comment: This definitely should be the accepted answer. Clean, simple, and works reliably.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you require a package installation due to dependencies, which are rare, I would recommend you use NVM (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install Node.

If you do this without sudo, you will also not need to use sudo when globally installing modules.

Comment: `nvm` requires setting up and maintaining special environment variables to work correctly. The recommendation to use `~/.local` as a prefix by contrast is convention used by a number of other programs and therefore ~/.local/bin may already in the path (or a future program will want to put something there). `n` can be used to manage multiple Node.js installs without environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

My edit to [Rowno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825428/10580490) has been rejected and I can't make a comment yet so I'll just post my version of the lines added in `.bashrc` here.

The edit I made in it was adding `export` to the assignments of NODE_PATH and MAN_PATH, and then simplifying the MANPATH assignment.  I also made `:` optional for NODE_PATH just in case it doesn't have a prior value.  The other modifications here are just personal preference but I haven't included them in the original edit.

```
npm_global=~/.npm-global
export NODE_PATH="$npm_global/lib/node_modules${NODE_PATH:+:}$NODE_PATH"
PATH="$npm_global/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$npm_global/share/man:$(unset MANPATH; manpath)"
```

Having `export` makes sure variables are shared across child processes that may need them (e.g. `node` and `man`), just in case they haven't been declared yet, or assigned with export attribute previously.  Specifying export to PATH OTOH is very much optional.

I actually find it unusual to reset MANPATH before prepending a value to it because some scripts may also add custom values to it earlier.  I recommend that the user makes sure `.bashrc` or any other user-based initialization scripts doesn't add other lines like this at least.  For global configurations, I think the path should be added formally through `/etc/manpath.config`, or something similar, so it's a different worry most likely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Either start a new terminal session or just type "source ~/.bashrc"
2. Now you can run any executables like grunt/bower/yo/whatever (depending on what npm packages you have installed globally).

P.S. BTW changing the global npm directory can be done with a command: npm config set prefix ~/global_npm

Comment: I think it's npm config set prefix?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much all you need to do if you are installing binary utilities (which I gather you are as you updated your `PATH`).

`NODE_PATH` will only need to be set you have installed a module that you want to `require()` from unrelated node scripts, but you shouldn't really do this anyway. Modules that are required as dependencies for other modules/scripts should be installed locally (i.e. specified in a `package.json`) as that way you keep strict control over versions.

Edit:
The accepted answer here explains it much better than I was able to:
[How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm)

Answer (score -1):

The answer by Rowno works for me, but only after making a slight edit to step 4:

```
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
```

and changed it to:

```
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
```