# NPM modules installation algorithm issue on ArchLinux

Tags: node.js, npm, archlinux, express-generator

I have a fresh installation of ArchLinux, NodeJS (v 5.2.0) and NPM (v 3.5.2). When I try to install any module (for example `express-generator` with `npm install express-generator`, same problem if I do it globally or any other package) the installation doesn't create a folder with the module's name in the node_modules folder and, inside, his own node_modules with its dependencies. Making myself clear, npm installs the modules and all his dependencies in the topmost level so, when I run a `ls`, I get something like this:

```
node_modules/
bootstrap commander express-generator mkdirp ... etc
```

Instead of:

```
node_modules/
bootstrap/
  node_modules/...
express-generator/
  node_modules/commander mkdirp ... etc
```

Recently, I tested this procedure in a virtual machine wiht Windows 7 and another with Debian 8 getting the second result. It happend with every module that I installed.

I don't know if that is a "new" behavior of npm's modules or a mistake in any of my configurations. Any help will be grateful. In advance, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm using the 5.2.0 version of Node and the 3.5.2 version of NPM.

Comment: Hi, I'm also having this issue on the latest version of Arch Linux, Node version 7.6.0 and NPM version 4.2.0. Have you been able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi TK421. It keeps working in this way. I'd have to install Arch on another pc and got the same behavior. I think that it is normal and depending on what OS you use. I would like to point out that I never have any functionality trouble with this behavior

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

`express-generator` should be installed globally (with `-g`). Even if you don't have root permissions, there are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088372/how-to-npm-install-global-not-as-root) for installing it globally. This way you have the `express` command made available to you so you can create an app skeleton. I don't find any value in local installation, regardless if it works or not.

Comment: Hi mihai thank you for your answer and excuse me for the delay in mine's. Even when I install the modules globally, npm keeps saving all the dependencies in one folder without split it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about dependencies for `express-generator`? They should be installed in the same (global) folder.

Comment: Excuse me, obviously I wasn't clear with my problem. The `express-generator` case was an example. When I install it or any other npm package (for instance `jshint`, `bootstrap`, etc) this modules doesn't create his own node_modules folder but put all the depencencies in the same folder, so I have the `express-generator`, `jshint`, `commander`, `mkdirp`, etc and all its dependencies in only one folder. In resume, after the installation of 2 or 3 npm packages, I have a unique node_modules folder with a heap of folders inside it.

Comment: ok, I see now. They are installed at the topmost level, see [algorithm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm). Indeed this behavior might've been different in the past, but I can't say for sure. Maybe if you rephrase your question you can get a better answer.