# how do i troubleshoot a program that isn't running in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

Publii is a desktop-based CMS for Windows, Mac and Linux.

I downloaded the appimage and deb packages and installed it, but neither seems to be launching, I have no way to troubleshoot why it isn't launching and I have used this software before on a previous installation of Ubuntu

How would I troubleshoot this program in Linux effectively? I'd prefer a terminal approach but a GUI is also good.

EDIT

following the instructions ran [here](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-publii-flat-file-cms-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10)

```
npm run dev

> Publii@0.31.3 dev /home/areahints/Publii
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --colors --watch

  0% compiling
Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 70ac0b5ea30dda937b0e                                                              
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 74137ms
                                    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
logo.svg?69939e5dc57509b76e1edb5d774413e3  3.45 kB          [emitted]         
logo.png?02b693904e442a91ab7b9ee7f0bbb84e  1.37 kB          [emitted]         
                                 build.js   7.1 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
 [112] ./app/src/main.js 4.63 kB {0} [built]
 [113] ./app/src/store/index.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
 [114] ./app/src/store/default.state.js 855 bytes {0} [built]
 [115] ./app/src/store/helpers/mutations.js 13.2 kB {0} [built]
 [117] ./app/src/store/getters/site-names.js 288 bytes {0} [built]
 [118] ./app/src/store/getters/site-display-names.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
 [119] ./app/src/store/getters/site-tags.js 826 bytes {0} [built]
 [120] ./app/src/store/getters/site-authors.js 2.51 kB {0} [built]
 [121] ./app/src/store/getters/site-posts.js 1.29 kB {0} [built]
 [125] ./app/src/store/getters/app-version.js 185 bytes {0} [built]
 [126] ./app/src/store/getters/themes.js 431 bytes {0} [built]
 [127] ./app/src/store/getters/theme-select.js 997 bytes {0} [built]
 [128] ./app/src/store/getters/tag-templates.js 534 bytes {0} [built]
 [130] ./app/src/router/index.js 3.17 kB {0} [built]
 [392] ./app/src/config/app-submenu.js 528 bytes {0} [built]
    + 514 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/display/panel.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 20:0-87
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/scroll/annotatescrollbar.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 17:0-110
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/scroll/scrollpastend.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 18:0-102
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 19:0-108
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/search/jump-to-line.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 12:0-98
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/search/match-highlighter.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 14:0-109
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 15:0-112
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/search/search.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 13:0-88
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules//codemirror/addon/search/searchcursor.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 16:0-100
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules/codemirror-advanceddialog/dist/advanced-dialog.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 21:0-111
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-3e787ac0","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules/codemirror-advanceddialog/dist/dialog.css' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-3e787ac0","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 4:10-131
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-3e787ac0","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules/codemirror-revisedsearch/dist/revised-search.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 22:0-108
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12a5d04f","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/src/components/App.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12a5d04f","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/src/components/App.vue 4:10-128
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-12a5d04f","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./app/src/components/App.vue
 @ ./app/src/components/App.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./app/src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src'
 @ ./app/src/main.js 43:0-82

ERROR in ./app/src/assets/vendor/js/codemirror/css.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'codemirror' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/assets/vendor/js/codemirror'
 @ ./app/src/assets/vendor/js/codemirror/css.js 5:0-36
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./app/src/assets/vendor/js/codemirror/xml.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'codemirror' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/assets/vendor/js/codemirror'
 @ ./app/src/assets/vendor/js/codemirror/xml.js 3:0-36
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'codemirror' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue 8:0-36
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/CodeMirrorEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./app/src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moment' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src'
 @ ./app/src/main.js 2:0-28

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/ColorPicker.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-color' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/basic-elements'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/basic-elements/ColorPicker.vue 21:0-35
 @ ./app/src/components/basic-elements/ColorPicker.vue
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./app/src/router/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-router' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/router'
 @ ./app/src/router/index.js 2:0-32
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/MenuItem.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuedraggable' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/MenuItem.vue 71:0-37
 @ ./app/src/components/MenuItem.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/Menus.vue
 @ ./app/src/components/Menus.vue
 @ ./app/src/router/index.js
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/Menus.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuedraggable' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/Menus.vue 156:0-37
 @ ./app/src/components/Menus.vue
 @ ./app/src/router/index.js
 @ ./app/src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/post-editor/GalleryPopup.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuedraggable' in '/home/areahints/Publii/app/src/components/post-editor'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/post-editor/GalleryPopup.vue 127:0-37
 @ ./app/src/components/post-editor/GalleryPopup.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./app/src/components/PostEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/components/PostEditor.vue
 @ ./app/src/router/index.js
 @ ./app/src/main.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this question is outside the realm of Stack Overflow, I looked into this.

It sounds like you installed the individual files and now cannot run program on Ubuntu.

To be honest, I would delete what you have downloaded and then start fresh by downloading solely thru the terminal.

I found this website that has directions to install via terminal.

[Install Publii Flat File CMS on Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 / 18.10](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-publii-flat-file-cms-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks @daniela-idara, when i used this method, npm throws so much errors i dont even know where to start

Comment: post the errors you get. errors normally have the answers. you might need to install additional packages to make it work.

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect the new errors @daniela-idara

Comment: node_modules errors for codemirror babel-loader vue-loader  - they are missing. for the updates: 'sudo apt-get update' then 'sudo apt-get upgrade' then, good to to update command again.  you will want to locate the exact error you had for the files that are missing. you need to install those too to make it work on your machine.

Comment: i uninstalled node, nodejs and npm, reinstalled them using NVM, installed all node packages that were dependencies on the Publii Github page, used gdebi to install the .deb file of the software and it worked immediately! thanks for your help.