# How to install node and npm on macOS without admin rights?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, sudo, macos-mojave

I work in a big organisation as UX designer. I have basic programming knowledge. I've been trying for ways to install node / npm on macOS without admin rights with no luck.

I've tried all the methods described here

https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

but all of them require using sudo or make which I cannot use

I've also downloaded the installer from nodejs.org and, unpack the file  with pkgutil but when  I run tar on the payloads they are copied to usr/local/bin/includes/node then I try to change the path in the host file but I need admin password to save.

I thought that this would be as easy as doing it on a Windows machine but it's not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to npm install global not as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088372/how-to-npm-install-global-not-as-root)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to download the [current version of node](https://nodejs.org/en/download)
Then go by [brew](https://brew.sh) with
`brew install -g npm`