# Reactjs installation failed

Tags: reactjs

I just changed a new laptop to MacBook air using Catalina. I was successfully installed Node when I tried install Reactjs but it says `'permission denied'` to node file as below:

```
zulfadliazhar@Zulfadlis-MacBook-Air ~ % npm install -g create-react-app
```

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall
>   access npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] { npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!
>   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR! } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The
>   operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely
>   you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current
>   user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions
>   issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and
>   its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again
>   as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/zulfadliazhar/.npm/_logs/2020-05-15T01_03_00_850Z-debug.log

```
zulfadliazhar@Zulfadlis-MacBook-Air ~ % create-react-app --version
```

> zsh: command not found: create-react-app

Please assist me.

Thank you

Comment: How did you install node?
If you use brew I think it won't be installed as root

Comment: sudo npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to npm install global not as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088372/how-to-npm-install-global-not-as-root)

Comment: use `npx create-react-app app-name`

Answer (score 0):

You need the sudo rights to install something in -g (it means global) because it will install it here => `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

so you just need to retry like this `sudo npm install -g create-react-app`