# Unable to instal globally npm packages

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, npm-install, adonis.js

I'm getting this error and can't find solution for it.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path /home/guzlej/.npm-global/lib
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/guzlej/.npm-global/lib'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/guzlej/.npm/_logs/2021-02-18T18_08_16_148Z-debug.log
```

Could you help me please? I'm happy to share debug.log

EDITED: I have been trying to install AdonisJs - Node.js framework. With first command in the guide "npm i -g @adonisjs/cli". I get this Error back.

Comment: Can you add please add more details? When the error occured?

Comment: I have been trying to install AdonisJs - Node.js framework. With first command in the guide "npm i -g @adonisjs/cli".

Comment: try install package with `sudo` or configure npm with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088372/how-to-npm-install-global-not-as-root

Comment: Hello crbast, thank you for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088372/how-to-npm-install-global-not-as-root didn't help aswell. I'm not sure what to do.