# node.js require doesn't work in script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small node script named `/tmp/test.js` containing this:

```
console.log(require("w3cjs"));
```

If I do this from the command prompt:

```
nvm use v0.10.21
node /tmp/test.js
```

I get this output:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'w3cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/test.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

But if I do this:

```
node -e $(cat /tmp/test.js)
```

I get this output:

```
{ validate: [Function: validate],
  setW3cCheckUrl: [Function: setW3cCheckUrl],
  w3cjs: [Circular] }
```

(In other words - it works.)

Why the difference and how do I make the script work?

Comment: I guess that node doesn't like to be /tmp-ed

Comment: Your `w3cjs` module is probably locally installed to a specific directory. Node uses the local modules installed within the directory of executed file. When you use `-e`, Node uses the local modules installed in your current directory.

Comment: @apsillers - If you made that an answer, I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run a script in a different directory, Node looks for local modules in the `node_modules` folder of that script's directory.

Suppose your shell's working directory is currently `/projects/foo`. When you run `node /tmp/test.js`, Node looks for modules in `/tmp/node_modules`, not in `/projects/foo/node_modules`.

However, if you don't run a script file, but run some text on the command line with `-e`, Node will check for a local module folder in your shell's current working directory, i.e., `/projects/foo/node_modules`.

It appears that you have `w3cjs` installed in your working directory, but not at `/tmp`. You should either install it there, or [install the module globally with `npm`'s `-g` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm).