# Trouble installing crossmon-server on Mac

Tags: node.js, monitoring, server-monitoring

Is there anyone here ever tried Crossmon-server? I've been searching Google to find any hint as to what I may be missing in the installation process but been unsuccessful. The basic steps are described here: https://npmjs.org/package/crossmon-server.

I'm installing it in OS X Mavericks with the latest Node version v0.10.24. After running

`richard:~ root# npm install crossmon-server` and do a `richard:~ root# which crossmon-server`

I still get nothing.... `crossmon-server` returns `-sh: crossmon-server: command not found`

*UPDATED*:

Installing globally with `-g` results into this error `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` So, I did both `sudo npm install crossmon-server -g` and `sudo su -` and re-ran the install command but still got this same error message:

```
> crossmon-server@0.0.15 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/crossmon-server
> npm i -g forever

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/rbm/.npm/28ef027b-forever.lock'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/rbm/.npm/28ef027b-forever.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/rbm/.npm/28ef027b-forever.lock' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "forever"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/crossmon-server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path /Users/rbm/.npm/28ef027b-forever.lock
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/rbm/.npm/28ef027b-forever.lock'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/crossmon-server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm ERR! crossmon-server@0.0.15 preinstall: `npm i -g forever`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the crossmon-server@0.0.15 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the crossmon-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm i -g forever
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls crossmon-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "crossmon-server" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/rbm/workspace/prototype-int/monitoring-service
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rbm/workspace/prototype-int/monitoring-service/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'd appreciate any help from anyone who have already tried this tool.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a module globally using npm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm)

Comment: Please see my additional comment above - your reference doesn't seem to be what will resolve my problem...

Comment: Read [this relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18277225/2137601) which helps you correctly configure `npm` on Mac OS while avoiding permission issues.

Comment: @PaulMougel, my error message has indicated it is 'likely' a problem with the crossmon-server package. And besides, my npm -g works fine with all the Node modules that I installed - crossmon-server is the only pain in my neck; And since this is my first time to develop on Mac, I prefer (for now) not to alter the basic behaviour of npm.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to expand your question with more logs: can you show us why `crossmon-server` fails to install? For what it's worth, this package's installation works on Mac Os 10.9.1 and node v0.10.23

Comment: I just updated with the entire console log. Hope that helps... Thanks in advance @PaulMougel

Comment: You're still facing the same permission issue: as you tried to run `sudo su- ; npm install -g ...` it created temporary files as root, which you can't delete now as a standard user. You have two solutions then: 1) remove those temporary files as root and re-run `sudo npm i -g crossmon-server`. Also search `npm EACCES Mac OS` on Google, you'll find plenty of answers 2) fix the `npm` installation directory as previously suggested (you'll just have to re-install all global packages but nothing else will change).

Comment: The above suggestions didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use crossmon-server from the command line, you have to install it globally:

```
npm install crossmon-server -g
```

Comment: Please see my additional comment above, it seems a problem more on the module itself...

Answer (score 0):

How I got this resolved is by cleaning up my environment by uninstalling my node, removed my entire .node_modules and removed all executable shortcuts of those packages inside.node_modules. I clean install my node using Homebrew and just installed grunt/mocha globally and all the rest just `npm install <package or module name>` - crossmon-server is installed locally within my proto-type project.

Hope this helps.