# package.json for global modules - not dependencies

Tags: npm

I would like to list some modules that I want to install globally - they are not project related (things like `bower`, `npm-check-updates`, ... which I use all the time). Is it possible to manage this with a "global" `package.json`, or do I need to maintain a separate shell script to perform this installation? Currently I am doing:

```
# global-npm-pacakges.sh

npm install -g npm-check-updates@1.5.1
npm install -g bower@1.4.1
```

Any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your way is fine but that means you also need to maintain another script to
uninstall all of them globally

Using npm install -g  with a global package.json,  you still have to manage a clean up script.
There is no npm uninstall -g based on the package.json.
I think you need to
    npm uninstall name<@version> or 
    npm -R name<@version>

Doing npm -R node_modules is not gracefully way of doing it.
It does not clean up the /tmp/xxx

There is some suggestions of using a symlink in this threads for your references:
[How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm)