# meanjs stack installation on OSX Yosemite: mean: command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, meanjs

I installed the mean stack using `npm install -g mean-cli` command without any errors. But when I want to start a mean project with `mean init myApp` I have `-bash: mean: command not found`. It seems to be easy to fix but so far I couldn't find the solution and it's blocking me since yesterday. Did anyone had the similar problem?

Thanks

EDIT

Here are installation logs :

```
mean-cli@0.10.12 preinstall /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
 node ./scripts/preinstall

npm WARN deprecated json-file-plus@2.0.0: Before v3.0.0, errors in fs.writeFile would not be propagated

 mean-health@0.1.7 postinstall /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mean-health
 node ./postinstall.js


 kerberos@0.0.11 install /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
 (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node: Finished

 bson-ext@0.1.7 install /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext
 (node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build) || (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node: Finished
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-init -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-init
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-authorize -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-authorize
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-login -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-login
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-addKey -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-addKey
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-publish -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-publish
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-whoami -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-whoami
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-register -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-register
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-postinstall -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-preinstall -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-preinstall
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-install -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-install
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-deploy -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-deploy
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-search -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-search
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-uninstall -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-uninstall
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-logs -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-logs
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-docs -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-docs
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-package -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-package
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-status -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-status
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-user -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-user
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-list -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-list
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-logout -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-logout
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-enable -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-enable
/Users/magrytos/.node/bin/mean-disable -> /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-disable
mean-cli@0.10.12 /Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
├── opener@1.4.1
├── async-series@0.0.1
├── progress@1.1.8
├── crypto@0.0.3
├── shelljs@0.3.0
├── commander@2.8.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── mean-health@0.1.7
├── npm@2.10.0
├── json-file-plus@2.0.0 (is@2.0.2, node.extend@1.1.3, promiseback@2.0.1)
├── prompt@0.2.14 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.6, winston@0.8.3, utile@0.2.1)
├── request@2.55.0 (caseless@0.9.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.6.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@2.4.2, tough-cookie@1.1.0, form-data@0.2.0, combined-stream@0.0.7, http-signature@0.10.1, mime-types@2.0.12, hawk@2.3.1, bl@0.9.4, har-validator@1.7.0)
├── inquirer@0.8.4 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.3.7, readline2@0.1.1, chalk@1.0.0, lodash@3.9.1, rx@2.5.2)
├── bower@1.4.1 (is-root@1.0.0, junk@1.0.1, stringify-object@1.0.1, user-home@1.1.1, abbrev@1.0.5, chmodr@0.1.0, rimraf@2.3.4, archy@1.0.0, opn@1.0.2, bower-logger@0.2.2, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, graceful-fs@3.0.7, lru-cache@2.6.4, lockfile@1.0.1, nopt@3.0.2, retry@0.6.1, tmp@0.0.24, q@1.4.1, chalk@1.0.0, request-progress@0.3.1, semver@2.3.2, promptly@0.2.0, fstream@1.0.6, mkdirp@0.5.0, shell-quote@1.4.3, p-throttler@0.1.1, bower-json@0.4.0, which@1.1.1, glob@4.5.3, fstream-ignore@1.0.2, tar-fs@1.5.1, insight@0.5.3, decompress-zip@0.1.0, request@2.53.0, update-notifier@0.3.2, github@0.2.4, bower-registry-client@0.3.0, cardinal@0.4.4, mout@0.11.0, bower-config@0.6.1, configstore@0.3.2, inquirer@0.8.0, handlebars@2.0.0)
└── mongoose@4.0.3 (regexp-clone@0.0.1, sliced@0.0.5, muri@1.0.0, hooks-fixed@1.0.1, mpromise@0.5.4, kareem@1.0.1, mpath@0.1.1, async@0.9.0, ms@0.1.0, mquery@1.5.1, mongodb@2.0.30, bson@0.3.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the npm modules directory to your path. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16635816/78496

Comment: Thanks @chedabob. I added `export PATH=/Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin:$PATH` to my .bash_profile.

Comment: It might be better to shorten that to just "/Users/magrytos/.node/lib/node_modules:$PATH" so that you can install other node command line tools in the future without having to edit your path again