# Electron-packager missing module 'electron-prebuilt'

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I made a computer app using HTML, CSS and JS but when I try to convert that app to exe file using electron-packager it shows me error

> Cannot find module 'electron-prebuilt' from 'C://myapp/helloworld/'

I am using windows.

This is the code

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    </script>


    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style_ie9.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## Main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

## Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package": "asar pack MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar",
    "build": "electron-packager . MyApp --ignore=node_modules/electron-* && cp Icon.icns MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/atom.icns"
  },
  "author": "Kyle Robinson Young <kyle@dontkry.com> (http://dontkry.com)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "asar": "^0.6.1",
    "electron-packager": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.25.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with electron, but would you need to do a `require('electron-prebuilt')`? In your Main.js right below `const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");`

Comment: try installing electron globally.

Comment: How can i install it globally? @rlemon

Comment: Nah it doesn't work @MannfromReno

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm lots of answers on how to do that.

Comment: still same problem @rlemon

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save electron-packager
```

Or if you're using a two package.json structure, you could try

```
npm install --save electron-packager
```

in both /app and higher directory.

Also, does this error occur when you run the `npm run pack` command?

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save electron-packager`?

Answer (score 0):

From the npm documentation:

> As of version 1.3.1, this package is published to npm under two names:
>   electron and electron-prebuilt. You can currently use either name, but
>   electron is recommended, as the electron-prebuilt name is deprecated,
>   and will only be published until the end of 2016.

Download and install the latest build of Electron for your OS and add it to your project's package.json as a devDependency:

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

> This is the preferred way to use Electron, as it doesn't require users
>   to install Electron globally.
>
> You can also use the -g flag (global) to symlink it into your PATH:

```
npm install -g electron
```