# Can I install node_modules once, and require all time

Tags: node.js

Same title.

I don't want install every time with any project.

Just install once.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know install global but **how to require it** is my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm)

Comment: You can install globally - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm But look carefully at the reasons you would do this. It does not make sense for something you might require especially as if you need to update it for one project you could update it for all with unintended consequences.

Comment: Just going to echo what's said above – you really probably don't want to do this, no matter how annoying it might feel to type in that `npm i --save something` for every project.

Comment: I think his mean is call `require`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Addenda: Package Manager Tips
Define `NODE_PATH` with path local modules, example:

- `/usr/lib/node_modules`
- `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules`
- Or anywhere you want

And now you can call it.

Since the module lookups using `node_modules` folders are all relative, and based on the real path of the files making the calls to `require()`, the packages themselves can be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. possible. Install all the modules globally.
ie; `npm install -g <module_name>`

Then use it in your application as necessary.

But, this method is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

After you install them global, use `npm link` in project folder with package names(see [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)), to link them to that project. e.g. if your project requires `lodash` use `npm link lodash`.

Another way, if you want to have multiple little scripts(e.g. not projects) you can   set the `NODE_PATH` variable with path to where your npm stores global packages. And after that `require('<global-module>')` will work without link and installing node_modules into folder.