# Adding electron application path to user environment variables after install

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron, electron-builder

**Problem description:**

---

I have an electron application and I need to add the application to user environment variables after users install my application, so that they can run commands like this `my-electron-app <command> [<args>]` in the terminal to start my electron application.

I could not find a way to do this programmatically using nodejs. VSCode, hyper and atom are the three electron apps ( *that I know of* ) who add the application path to user environment variables after users install the application.

I'm using [electron builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to build an NSIS installer. I couldn't find any options there either that serve the purpose.

**Question:**

---

How can I add my electron application to *user environment variables* after users install my application on their system, so that they can launch my electron app from terminal by running commands like this `my-electron-app start`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm)

Comment: I suppose you could generate a bash script on first launch and save it to `/usr/local/bin/` or similar. On macOS you can simply use `open -a YourApp yourFile`.

Comment: Any update? Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am blindly guessing here since I have simply browsed through the code for a couple of minutes: There seems to be a [post install step](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/templates/linux/after-install.tpl) which is maybe also [used in Hyper](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/blob/canary/build/linux/after-install.tpl) [here](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/blob/canary/package.json#L166) somehow. This script places a file in a folder that is probably in the user's `PATH`. More about the PATH environment variable [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).