# How can i add electron install location to PATH variable after install

Tags: node.js, electron, environment-variables, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder to package my electron app. 
My app has a CLI module, so what I need is: 
- After I finish installing the application (using `allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true`), I need to add the install location to the PATH variable. 
I can't find anything on this but this question [Adding electron application path to user environment variables after install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412841/adding-electron-application-path-to-user-environment-variables-after-install), which doesn't have a viable answer

Answer (score 5):

I have made it work like this:

- Download [`EnvVarUpdate.nsh`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/images/a/ad/EnvVarUpdate.7z)
- Save it in the same folder as `installer.nsh`
- Add the following to your `package.json`:

```
{
  // ...
  "build": {
    // ...
    "nsis": {
      "warningsAsErrors": false
    }
  }
}
```

- In `installer.nsh` add:

```
!include "EnvVarUpdate.nsh"
!macro customInstall
    ${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "$INSTDIR"
!macroend
!macro customUnInstall
    ${un.EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "R" "HKLM" "$INSTDIR"
!macroend
```

This updates the path variable with the instalation dir on install and deletes it on uninstall.

Comment: I get an error during the installation if I don't run it as Administrator on Windows 10: `Could not write updated PATH to HKLM` any ideas? On Windows 10 normal users have their own PATH variable which should be editable.

Comment: i have a package I'm creating with electron-installer but I don;t see installer.nsh anywhere... where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Within electron-builder you can use a custom NSIS script, which will be executed during installation progress: [Electron-Builder custom NSIS script](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script)

To detect the intallation directory you can use the param $INSTDIR in the NSIS custom script.

The NSIS documentation describe the PATH manipulation: [NSIS PATH manipulation](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Path_Manipulation)

See below an example for you custom NSIS script to append the install directory to the PATH (build/installer.nsh):

```
!macro preInit
   ${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "$INSTDIR"
!macroend
```

Comment: I did this but i get this error:  
  
`Invalid command: "${EnvVarUpdate}"  
Error in macro preInit on macroline 1`

Comment: I fixed it. Just that i had to download `EnvVarUpdate.nsh` first and i used `!macro customInstall` instead of `!macro preInit`(this didnt work)