# Question regarding NPM, ReactJS, and installed packages both globally, and locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Question regarding NPM, ReactJS, and installed packages both globally, and locally.  I have done quite of bit of searching and found no real resolution.  Here's my main App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import ReactLogger from 'react-terminal-logger/console-logger'
import 'whatwg-fetch'
import Intro from '../Intro/Intro'
import './app.css'

// ReactLogger.config({
//     visible: ['log', 'error', 'info', 'warn', 'logr'],
//     save_logs: false,
//     only_msg: true,
//     port: 1234,
//     stacktrace_hide: true,
// })

// ReactLogger.start()

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        series: [],
        logs: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Hook(window.console, (log) => {
        //     this.setState(({ logs }) => ({ logs: [...logs, Decode(log)] }))
        // })

        fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=Vikings').then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            // logr(response)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title">TV Series List</h1>
                </header>
                <Intro message="Here you can find all you most loved series!" />
                The length of the series array is - {this.state.series.length}{' '}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Any time I install a package globally, so I can reuse it in other projects I end up with an error when I try to start the server.  Such as the logging package (above) react-terminal-logger. I used the following steps:

1. npm install -g react-terminal-logger
2. added import and initialized components as per instructions
3. tried to use component (eg. logr(response))

I end up with the same error at compile time no matter what I installed globally and add to my project.

```
C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\Documents\ProjectsDirectory\Projects\reactjsx-tutorial-old\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\Application Data'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\DawsonSchaffer\\Application Data'
}
```

My global package prefix points to "C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\AppData\Roaming\npm" which is the default.  If I simply remove the components use by it commenting out everything works.

How do I resolve this? What is the proper way to install a new global package and add it to an existing project?  What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

One other note, if I install the component locally in my project it works fine.  Overall point though is too not have to install it in every project.

Thanks
Dawson

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand here is that the global install option of common JS package managers is not intended to facilitate shared project dependencies. To clarify, [from NPM itself](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally):

> Installing a package globally allows you to use the code in the package as a set of tools on your local computer.

With that out of the way, the optimization you're looking for is a real one, but for different reasons than you may think. When thinking about dependency management, you're really thinking about a small subset of pros and cons related to deciding whether you want use a [mono-repo, multi-repo (microservices) or some hybrid](https://hackernoon.com/mono-repo-vs-multi-repo-vs-hybrid-whats-the-right-approach-dv1a3ugn).

If you're dealing with entirely different projects that are using the same dependency, then ignore the previous paragraph as they should definitely each manage their own dependencies independently.

Comment: I'm 90% of the way there.  I look at it this way I think? I originally setup for React development I installed react, react-dom, create-react-app, and react-scripts (using npm install -g).  For right or wrong when I create a new project with npx create-react-app the project already has access to packages mentioned.  So:

1) How would I get a package (eg. react-terminal-logger) to a part of a default new project without additional steps?

2) Why do I get the error referencing ,my "Application Directory" when I use said package (wrongly installed) with npm -g without installing in project?

Comment: @DawsonMSchaffer None of the packages you installed globally should be there as they are not to be used as CLI tools on your local computer. As you have observed, the necessary dependencies are scaffolded in via CRA. 1. You should simply `npm install` any additional dependencies for your project beyond the scaffold. 2. The error you are seeing is due to global packages being out of scope for your project.

Comment: So I uninstall react, react-dom, and react-scripts from global; leaving me with only **create-react-app**.  One I create a new project I just install the previously mentioned packages, correct?  Perhaps this should be a separate question but it seems to apply here.  What would be the best method for creating my own boilerplate  project so I can use **npx createreact-app** to have a common starting point with packages I use in each project?  I really appreciate the help you have cleared up so much for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer could help you:
[How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm)

Usually, global installation are meant to be for CLI tools or executable tools.

Comment: Yes thanks that's what I did for better or worse and got myself into trouble :-).

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it all straightened out.  I uninstalled react, react-dom, and react-scripts from global; leaving me with only create-react-app.  I created an empty project called react-boilerplate, and installed react, react-dom, react-scripts, and react-router-dom in the new project.  I then uploaded to my GitHub account so I have a common starting point for new projects.  Should have thought about this before but it took me a while to wrap my head around everything.  Now I can update my boilerplate as needed, and use it to clone as a starting point for new projects.  Yeah!

Thanks to everyone especially Dennis G for all his help!!

Dawson